# Do I need to call do_action in my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, actions

Do I need to call `do_action` function every time I `add_action` something?

Comment: Why do you think you should? Example code?

Comment: I was exploring the codes of `WooCommerce` plug-in, they've called `do_action` a lot of time. I'm new to Wordpress and thinking of building a plug-in, so I was checking out some existing codes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, you use existing action in your plugins. WordPress will call `do_action()` when needed.

If your plugin is rather complex, like a shopping plugin, you may want to offer additional actions for other plugin developers or for the pro-version of your plugin. In these cases you add `do_action()` wherever you think it could be useful.

An example: I have a library of PHP classes that I use for some projects. When I write a plugin that relies on my library I have to wait until the library is ready. So I write in my library:

```
require 'class.T5_Custom_Post_Type_Helper.php';
require 'class.T5_Custom_Taxonomy_Helper.php';
// and so on…
do_action( 't5_library_loaded' );
```

In my other plugin I hook into this action to start all the work:

```
add_action( 't5_library_loaded', array ( 'My_Plugin_Class', 'init' ) );
```

Now I know all needed classes available, I don’t have to test `class_exists()` each time.

`add_action()` and `do_action()` are not necessary tied together. So the answer to your question is: no. :)