# Difference between do_action and add_action

Tags: hooks, actions

This question might be wrong, I am not sure about it. Because I am not clear on this.

I know `add_action` it is used to to hook our function to the specified function. For example `add_action('wp_head'.'myfunc');` now what ever code in `myfunc` will be executed in the `wp_head()`. This is clear but i am having doubt in `do_action` what it does?

I think it is used to create our own hook like already available hooks(wp_head,wp_footer,..etc) If i am correct can anyone show me a simple understandable answer with simple example.

I have tried the difference in internet but all are pointing to difference between add_action and add_filter. I don't want to go there because first i want to clarify this and then I’ll move there.

Can anybody help me?

**EDIT** after Question POST

```
function custom_register()
{
    echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert("Learning Hooks");});</script>';

}
do_action('custom');

add_action('custom','custom_register');
```

I tried this in plugin but i didn't get the alert message.

But when i hook the same function with `wp_head` then it is working fine

```
/******************working****************/
add_action('wp_head','custom_register');
```

Comment: What happens when you call `do_action('custom');` **after** you registered the callback? And make sure jQuery is loaded.

Comment: i did not get the alert message either on back end or front end

Comment: jQuery are loaded. When i hook the same function with `wp_head` it is working fine but not with the `custom`

Comment: Sun, I believe your original Question was answered by toscho and you should mark this as resolved. The edits #3 an #4 that you've done belong on a [new Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `do_action( 'unique_name' )` to create your own actions.

You can use that to offer an [API for your plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98783/73), so other plugins can register callbacks for your custom action. Example: [Do I need to call do_action in my plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64678/73)

But you can use custom actions (or filters) in a theme too. Example: [Best practice way to implement custom sections into a WordPress theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99958/73)

And you can combine both to make a plugin and a theme working together. Example: [How to make method from plugin available in theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116317/73)

Summary: `add_action( 'foo' )` registers a callback, `do_action( 'foo' )` executes that registered callback.

Comment: Thanks for the help i got this is mainly for API purpose. I tried a sample but it didn't work out.Can you find any problem there? Check my EDIT @toscho

Comment: Can we say this as another case like inheritance? intead of extending and overriding the class we are going this way. Is this correct?

Comment: @sun Hm, yes, but you can [combine both approaches](http://wpkrauts.com/2013/initialize-a-plugin-with-a-configuration-object/), they are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

This is my guess, so if you know better, please make a comment so I can update my guess.

Your plugin code is executed before `wp_head()` (which we can assume will invoke the actions added to it). When you `add_action('wp_head','custom_register')`, you are telling PHP that when (in the future) `do_action('wp_head')` is called, to call `custom_register()` as well.  The same is true of your call to `add_action('custom','custom_register')` but as you see in your code, the call to `do_action('custom')` has already been made, and when it was called, there was not (yet) any action added to it.
This is why Toscho asked what happens when you call `do_action('custom')` **after** you registered the callback.  Your answer about back end and front end is ambiguous.  If you swap the last two lines in the following code, I think it will work:

```
function custom_register()
{
    echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert("Learning Hooks");});</script>';

}
do_action('custom');                    // This is called before it will have an effect.

add_action('custom','custom_register'); // Too late - do_action was already called.
```

Answer (score 1):

`do_action` : Registers an **action hook** while
`add_action` : **adds a callback function** to the registered hook.

**Example**

Consider you wanted to print something before sidebar in you template.

1. You will add an **action hook** in your template file `index.php` via `<?php add_action('bp_sidebar_left'); ?>`.
2. Now in your `functions.php` file you can add a callback function to that hook to print something you want.

`add_action('bp_sidebar_left', 'bp_sidebar_left_cb');
function bp_sidebar_left_cb() {
    echo 'Hello World !';
}`

Comment: What does it mean to 'register a hook'? Where is it being registered?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use like below:

```
function custom_register()
{
    echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert("Learning Hooks");});</script>';

}
.

add_action('custom','custom_register'); // Too late - do_action was already called. 
do_action('custom');                    // This is called before it will have an effect
```

Comment: It is working for me